# Group By/Distinct in Access 2007

Tags: group-by, ms-access-2007, distinct

I have a query in which I select multiple columns, but only need the results to return a distinct set of data:

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT REQUIRED_TOOLS.REQUIRED_TOOL_NSN, REQUIRED_TOOLS.REQUIRED_TOOL_NAME, REQUIRED_TOOLS.ID, OEM_MASTER.OEM_No, REQUIRED_TOOLS.IS_TEST_EQUIP, OEM_MASTER.OEM_IN_INVENTORY, AIRCRAFT_EQUIPMENT.ID"

strSQL = strSQL & " FROM (OEM_MASTER INNER JOIN (REQUIRED_TOOLS INNER JOIN REL_OEM_TO_NSN ON REQUIRED_TOOLS.ID = REL_OEM_TO_NSN.NSN_REF_ID) ON OEM_MASTER.ID = REL_OEM_TO_NSN.OEM_REF_ID) INNER JOIN (AIRCRAFT_EQUIPMENT INNER JOIN REL_AC_EQUIP_TO_TOOLS ON AIRCRAFT_EQUIPMENT.ID = REL_AC_EQUIP_TO_TOOLS.AC_EQUIP_ID) ON REQUIRED_TOOLS.ID = REL_AC_EQUIP_TO_TOOLS.TOOL_ID"

strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((REQUIRED_TOOLS.IS_TEST_EQUIP)=No) AND ((OEM_MASTER.OEM_IN_INVENTORY)=Yes) AND ((AIRCRAFT_EQUIPMENT.ID)=" & Me.List0.Column(2) & "))"

strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY REQUIRED_TOOLS.REQUIRED_TOOL_NAME"

Me.List1.RowSource = strSQ
```

When I comment out the group by clause, I get results, but multiple results of REQUIRED_TOOL_NAME (which only exist in its own table once, but can have multiple OEM_MASTER.OEM_No references in the OEM_MASTER.OEM_No table/column). I need to filter out all repeat instances in my list.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some data here to show us what you're getting vs. what you'd like to get?  That would make it easier to figure out.

Comment: My apologies. Short problem is that I cannot get the group by clause to work. REQUIRED_TOOLS.REQUIRED_TOOL_NAME is one-to-many to OEM_MASTER.OEM_No, but I only want to return the first record instead if n number (based on the number of related records in OEM_MASTER.OEM_No). Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: The GROUP BY clause won't work the way you're trying to use it here.  When you only show one of each tool, what do you want to happen to the OEM_No field?  If you use GROUP BY on one field, you have to include all the other fields as well, or use a function like SUM() MAX() AVG() on them instead.